# How to clear a form having inputs with same ng-model, with a button?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form, which is  putting input fields according to what i select previously, so i can have different number of inputs in my form. i have tried with something like this:

```
$scope.person = {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe"
    };

    var oriPerson = angular.copy($scope.person);
$scope.resetForm = function ()
    {
      $scope.person = angular.copy(oriPerson);
      $scope.personForm.$setPristine();
    };
```

but the problem is that i can have inputs with same ng-model, so for example when i try to write "blabla" in the input with ng-model="integer", it automatically puts the "blabla" in the other inputs with ng-model="integer". Help?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the good practice to have multple model with same name :-p

Answer (score 0):

You are binding multiple controls to the same property, ng-model binds the control to a property, in your case the property is "integer".   You will need different properties if you want it to act differently.  i.e. interger, coolInteger, dumbInteger, awesomeInteger... ect.  Those can have the

If you are adding inputs based on selection, you will need to have logic that will name the ng-model differently so they are not bound to the same value.  If the value is tied to the person, you could base the name on the person in your scope, like:

```
ng-model="person.firstName"
```

Then if you have multiple people, you can copy what you want, where you want it.

```
$scope.resetForm = function ()
{
  $scope.person2 =  $scope.person;
  $scope.person = null;
  // whatever else....
};
```

Then the bound inputs of person.firstName are cleared out, and you have your copy.  Hope that helps.